# Can I create an inline function/method inside of a user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create an inline function/method inside of my user control, so that I can do this:

Inside my test.ascx:

```
<asp:Repeater ...>
  <itemTemplate>
     <p><%# MyInlineMethod(Eval("hello").ToString())%> </p>
  <itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

is this possible?

Comment: In most cases it's better to perform such operations on the data before binding it to the data source, while this can work, it's generally more error prone and time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but it has to be `static` method. And you will have to access it with fully qualified name or import the namespace.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="RootNamespace.SubNamespace1" %>

<asp:Repeater ...>
  <itemTemplate>
     <p><%# MyClass.MyInlineMethod(Eval("hello").ToString())%> </p>
  <itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

*Method definition*

```
namespace RootNamespace.SubNamespace1
{
     public class MyClass
     {
         public static string MyInlineMethod(string input){
            return string.Format("{0}!!!",input);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<!-- IsActive is a boolean property of a bound item -->
<div class="<%# WebUtils.GetStyleName((bool)Eval("IsActive")) %>" />
```

```cs
public class WebUtils
{
   public static string GetStyleName(bool isActive)
   {
         return isActive ? "activeStyleName" : "notactiveStyleName";
   }
}
```